# How to use jCarousel with PHP function?

Tags: php, jquery, jcarousel

I'm still learning both PHP and jQuery, and this seems to me to be a reasonably complex thing to try and do.

What I'd like to be able to do is use jCarousel's textscroller capability to display a list of URLs generated by a PHP function rather than the XML feed and URLs that jCarousel is written for. (Demo: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/special_textscroller.html)

The WordPress PHP function I want to use generates a list of URLs with some html markup for some or all posts in a WordPress category.

As a result, I think I don't need jCarousel's XML function or the html creator function, and I don't need to truncate strings.

So, is it possible to include the PHP function in the jQuery function, or would I have the jQuery function retrieve the URL list from the PHP function, something similar to providing a XML feed to jCarousel? Do I need to use the jQuery-PHP library? http://jquery.hohli.com

Any answers will be appreciated. - Mark

This are the jCarousel functions that use the XML feed: (I omitted document ready function)

```
function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel, state)
{

    carousel.lock();

    jQuery.get(
        'special_textscroller.php',
        {
            'feed': 'http://jquery.com/blog/feed/atom/'
        },
        function(xml) {
            mycarousel_itemAddCallback(carousel, xml);
        },
        'xml'
    );
};

function mycarousel_itemAddCallback(carousel, xml)
{
    var $items = jQuery('item', xml);

    $items.each(function(i) {
        carousel.add(i + 1, mycarousel_getItemHTML(this));
    });

    carousel.size($items.size());

    // Unlock and setup.
    carousel.unlock();
    carousel.setup();
};

/**
 * Item html creation helper.
 */
function mycarousel_getItemHTML(item)
{
    return '<h3><a href="'+$('link', item).text()+'">'+$('title', item).text()+'</a></h3><p>'+mycarousel_truncate($('description', item).text(), 90)+'</p>';
};

/**
 * Utility function for truncating a string without breaking words.
 */
function mycarousel_truncate(str, length, suffix) {
    if (str.length <= length) {
        return str;
    }

    if (suffix == undefined) {
        suffix = '...';
    }

    return str.substr(0, length).replace(/\s+?(\S+)?$/g, '') + suffix;
};
```

And this WordPress PHP function:

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=mycategory&showposts=10'); ?><?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br /><br /><?php endwhile; ?>
```

generates html like this:

```
<a href="URL" rel="bookmark">link title</a><br /><br /><a href="URL" rel="bookmark">link title</a><br /><br />,  etc....
```

which is the html I'd like the jCarousel text scroller to display.

Answer (score 0):

you seem to be missing the actual call to start the carousel

the html needs to be wrapped in a div

```
<div id="mycarousel"> 
   <a href="URL" rel="bookmark">link title</a><br /><br />
   <a href="URL" rel="bookmark">link title</a><br /><br />,  etc....
</div>
```

then call

```
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
    vertical: true,
    size: 0,
    initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
});
```

Comment: I ommitted the HTML code that goes in the body of the page for clarity; what I'm trying to figure out is how to get jCarousel to use the list of URLs that the PHP functions generates rather than the XML feed in the original function

Answer (score 0):

in

```
function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel, state){

carousel.lock();

jQuery.get(
    'special_textscroller.php',
    {
        'feed': 'http://jquery.com/blog/feed/atom/'
    },
    function(xml) {
        mycarousel_itemAddCallback(carousel, xml);
    },
    'xml'
);};
```

this method you need to put your WP-php file name in place of "special_textscroller.php" 
file or can change the  "special_textscroller.php" with your WP function .

Again , you need to send output via XML format only if you do not want to change other "jCarousel" functions.